# convert nested lists to string

Tags: python, string, list, nested

How can I convert the following `list` to a `string`?

```
list1= [[1, '1', 1], [2,'2',2], [3,'3',3]]

Result: '1 1 1'
        '2 2 2'
        '3 3 3'
```

Thanks

Comment: I removed the python tag because it was not put there by the poster and as others have pointed out it could be Ruby.

Comment: Thanks Colin, my mistake.  And I have been doing a little Ruby coding lately too!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ended up with this:

```
for a, b, c in data:
    print(repr(a)+' '+repr(b)+' '+repr(c))
```

i had to write the output to a `textfile`, in which the write() method could only take type `str`, this is where the `repr()` function came in handy

```
repr()- Input: object; Output: str
```

...shoulda stated I was working in Python tho...thanks for the input

Answer (score 9):

Looks like Python.  List comprehensions make this easy:

```
list1= [[1, '1', 1], [2,'2',2], [3,'3',3]]
outlst = [' '.join([str(c) for c in lst]) for lst in list1]
```

Output:

```
['1 1 1', '2 2 2', '3 3 3']
```

Comment: There is no need in square brackets inside `join()` it could be: `' '.join(str(c) for c in lst)` or `' '.join(map(str, lst))`.

Answer (score 3):

Faster and Easier way:

```
Result = " ".join([' '.join([str(c) for c in lst]) for lst in list1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call join on each of the arrays. Ex:

```
list1= [[1, '1', 1], [2,'2',2], [3,'3',3]]

stringified_groups = []

list1.each do |group|
  stringified_groups << "'#{group.join(" ")}'"
end

result = stringified_groups.join(" ")

puts result
```

This loops through each of the groups. It joins the groups with a space, then wraps it in single quotes. Each of these groups are saved into an array, this helps formatting in the next step.

Like before the strings are joined with a space. Then the result is printed.

Comment: Chris, the Python tag wasn't put there by the poster.  I have removed it since it, as you and cloudhead assumed, could be Ruby.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion.  I added the Python tag.  Thanks to Colin for removing.

Answer (score 1):

here is a one liner

```
>>> print "'"+"' '".join(map(lambda a:' '.join(map(str, a)), list1))+"'"
'1 1 1' '2 2 2' '3 3 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_list_values(data_structure, temp=[]):
    for item in data_structure:
        if type(item) == list:
            temp = get_list_values(item, temp)

        else:
            temp.append(item)

    return temp


nested_list = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], 'e', ['g', 'h', ['i', 'j', ['k', 'l']]]]
print(', '.join(get_list_values(nested_list)))
```

**Output:**

```
a, b, c, d, e, g, h, i, j, k, l
```

Comment: Please consider adding details in your codes/answers, so others can also benefit from your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Could be ruby too, in which case you'd do something like:

```
list = [[1, '1', 1], [2,'2',2], [3,'3',3]]
list.join(' ')
```

which would result in "1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3"